# Слияние двух Observable массивов

Tags: angular, rxjs, concat

Есть поток №1 - `initMessages$` В него приходят первые 10 сообщений для рендера. 
Есть поток №2 = `newMessages$` при срабатывании эвента, идет запрос в базу, на следующие 10 сообщений.

Как мне Обновить мой поток №1 `initMessages$` и передать в него значания из второго потока ?
Возможен ли какой-либо вариант аля:

```
initMessages$ = [...initMessages$,...newMessages$]
```

Использую RxJs, Angular, Apollo (graphql).

upd:
На данный момент `initMessages$` получаю вот так

`this.chatService.getMessagesForCurrentChat( this.currentDriver.chatId, this.chatCurrentPage )` сервис возвращает Observable, список элементов рендерится при помощи `async pipe`.
Сейчас я реализую пагинацию сообщений в чате. При прокрутке вверх, срабатывает `Event` и он эмитит функцию в которой я выполняю запрос на следующие 10 сообщений из базы `this.newMessages$ = this.chatService.getMessagesForCurrentChat( this.currentDriver.chatId, this.chatCurrentPage );` сервис возвращает `.valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.allDriverMessage[0].messages));` и в этой же функции я хочу добавить эти новые 10 сообщений, в уже существующие `initMessages$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представим, что `initMessages$` это:

```
const initMessages$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

При подписке этот поток сгенерирует 5 значений. Представим, что `newMessages$` это:

```
const newMessages$ = from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);
```

Нам нужна фабрика которая параметром принимает потоки, подписывается на них и генерирует события поочередно от каждого потока:

```
concat(initMessages$, newMessages$).subscribe(value => {
  console.log(`value = ${value}`);
});
```

Результатом будет генерация 10 событий и завершение:

```
value = 1
value = 2
value = 3
value = 4
value = 5
value = a
value = b
value = c
value = d
value = e
```

А теперь нам нужно объединить все события в массив:

```
concat(initMessages$, newMessages$)
  .pipe(toArray())
  .subscribe(value => {
    console.log('is array = ', Array.isArray(value));
    console.log(`value = `, value);
  });
```

Результатом будет генерация 1 события и завершение:

```
is array = true
value = [
  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
]
```

---

P.S. можно и `merge` использовать, все зависит от поставленной задачи.

---

**UPD: ты чуть-чуть усложнил свою задачу.**

Логику пагинации я бы реализовал так:

- Есть сервис пагинации, у которого есть генератор событий `Subject<number>`
- Генератор событий, являясь одновременно потоком, проецируется на поток загрузки сообщений через `concatMap` (для очередей, другие операторы не подходят)

Псевдокод ниже:

```
@Injectable()
export class PaginationService {
  paginate$ = new Subject<number>();
}
```

Где-то в компоненте, который отвечает за пагинацию:

```
export class PaginationComponent {
  constructor(private paginationService: PaginationService) {}

  paginate(page: number): void {
    this.paginationService.paginate$.next(page);
  }
}
```

И в компоненте выше, который отвечает за рендеринг сообщений:

```
export class MessagesComponent {
  messages$ = this.paginationService.paginate$.pipe(
    startWith(1),
    concatMap(page =>
      this.chatService.getMessagesForCurrentChat(this.currentDriver.chatId, page)
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private chatService: ChatService,
    private paginationService: PaginationService
  ) {}
}
```

`messages$` передаешь параметром в конвеер `async` - `messages$ | async`. `startWith(1)` означает сразу сгенерировать число 1, дабы пользователю загрузились сообщения со страницы 1, а потом при скролле уже генерируются события со значением 2/3/4/5 (страницы) и грузятся соответствующие сообщения.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде бы с `merge` стало что-то получаться. Но возник такой вопрос: Как дождаться выполнения второго запроса в базу (newMessages$) и только после этого, добавить его в merge ?

Comment: а как выглядит `newMessages$`?

Comment: `this.newMessages$ = this.chatService.getMessagesForCurrentChat(
      this.currentDriver.chatId,
      this.chatCurrentPage
    );`  сервис возвращает Apollo запрос вот его конец -  ` .valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.allDriverMessage[0].messages));`

Comment: добавь это в свой вопрос в отформатированном виде. в комментарии плохо понятно. Объясни задачу, потому что с твоего более простого вопроса начинает выплывать более сложный :)

Comment: Спасибо, не увидел сразу твой ответ. Накатал то, как я решил задачку. Завтра попробую выйнести пагинацию в отдельный сервис. Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ.

Comment: @NikolayBarda не за что, обращайся 

Comment: Такс, попробовал я твой вариант, с concatMap первый раз все отработало как нужно... Но вот второй раз, уже не хочет выполнятся запрос в мой chat.service .... с mergeMap запрос идет, но он мне показывает в окне чата сначала первые 10 сообщений, потом следующие 10 сообщений ,итд  то есть как будто перелистываю старницы, а мне надо, чтобы message$ сохранял предыдущие сообщения... не знаю, что делать :(

Comment: @NikolayBarda я кажись понимаю о чем ты. А есть ли у тебя возможность добавить к `.valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.allDriverMessage[0].messages))` еще `take(1)` после `map`? Что такое `valueChanges`? Я просто не знаком с Аполло, но по названию это похоже на поток, который не auto-complete. Выходит так что `concatMap` подписывается на него и ждет завершения, а он не завершается, возможно стоит помочь ему

Comment: ты просто восхетителен :) Надеюсь, я смогу так же углубиться в познаниях Angulara и RxJs . valueChanges таки да возвращает Observable. И take(1) СРаботал как надо. И concatMap начал работать, но ситуация такая же, как и с mergeMap отображает следующие  10 сообщений, а не конкотенирует новые со старыми :( Может где-то аккумулятор не передаю ?

Comment: Добавил Scan и все заработало :)  this.messages$ = this.paginationService.paginate$.pipe(
  startWith(0),
  concatMap(page => {
    console.log('page', page);
    return this.chatService.getMessagesForCurrentChat(driverId, page)
  }
  ),
  scan((o, n)=> n.concat(o) )
);

Comment: @NikolayBarda ))) Если `scan` помогает тебе в решении проблемы, то дай Бог, опять же - я просто не знаю всей твоей бизнес логики и как оно все реализовано. В чем проблема `mergeMap`? `mergeMap` будет порождать параллельные запросы `getMessagesForCurrentChat` и может быть ситуация, что сервер на запрос отправленный ранее ответит позже, чем на запрос, отправленный позже. `concatMap` убирает это недетерменированное поведение, создавая под капотом очередь, он гарантирует, что все сообщения будут идти друг за дружкой как им и положено. С RxJS у тебя все будет хорошо, нужно просто подучить операторы

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил, вот таким образом 
`this.messages$ = merge(this.messages$, this.newMessages$).pipe(
      scan((oldMess, newMess) => [...oldMess,...newMess])
    );`
`rxjs merge` - дал мне на выходе два массива, старыми и новыми сообщениями. а `rxjs scan` объединил их в один, общий массив. Вроде бы работает как нужно.
Спасибо overthesanity за то, что натолкнул на rxjs merge.